# Как подключить таблицы стилей

Tags: css3, вёрстка, css

Друзья сложилась проблемка мне нужно подключить разные таблици стилей в зависимости от разрешения экрана пишу следующий код.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo2.css" media="only screen and (max-height: 768px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" media="only screen and (min-height: 800px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" media="only screen and (max-height: 768px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="only screen and (min-height: 800px)"  />
```

На запрос `max-height: 768px` все работает замечательно но если смотрю на другом мониторе на котором по идее должен сработать `min-height: 800px`, он не работает и сайт стоит без стилей вообще. Подскажите, как это поправить.

Comment: а на мониторе какого разрешения смотришь?

Comment: Сначала смотрю на буке 1366 на 768 потом на компе 1400 на 900

Comment: У меня та самая задача...Что ты используешь для IE?

Comment: У меня не в одном браузере эта штука не работает

Comment: Для IE ничего не использую

Answer (score 1):

Еще должно сработать, если заменить `min-height` на `min-device-height`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение своей проблемы с помощью JavaScript. Единственный недостаток что страницу в некоторых случаях приходиться обновлять дважды.

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    if (screen.height <= '1024') {
       document.write ('<link href="style1024.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'); 
    }; 
    //-->
    </script>
```

Comment: Не очень решение, чем вам это не угодило: `@import "/path/to/style.css" screen and (max-width: 1024px);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте один главный файл стилей main.css, и лепите там:

`@import "/path/to/style.css" screen and (max-width: 1280px);`

И это чистый CSS, а если занимаетесь вёрсткой профессионально (или планируете) то используйте препроцессор, например такой: http://compass-style.org

Там все такие проблемы решаются ещё проще и удобнее такой штукой как SASS\SCSS Media Query Mixin ( http://paranoida.github.io/sass-mediaqueries/ ) + много всяких плюшек, таких как возможнось всё минимизировать сразу и скажем забыть про вендорные префиксы.